# Preform Full-Text search on multiple tables

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I have full-text search implemented in my asp.net site that works when searching one table.  However, I want the user to be able to search two completely different tables simultaneously.  I am trying this with the following code:

```
  public List<Article> Search(List<string> keywords)
    { 
        StringBuilder sqlBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        sqlBuilder.Append("select [aName],[aDesc] from [Table1]  union select [bName],[bDesc] from [Table2] where");

        foreach (string item in keywords)
        {
            sqlBuilder.AppendFormat("([bName] like '%{0}%' or [bDesc] like '%{0}%') and ", item);
        }


       //foreach (string item in keywords)
        //{
            //sqlBuilder.AppendFormat("([aName] like '%{0}%' or [aDesc] like '%{0}%') and    ", item);
       //}


        string sql = sqlBuilder.ToString(0, sqlBuilder.Length - 4);
        return QueryList(sql);

    }
```

This code always displays all the records from my first table, and only performs the search on the second table. Now this is obviously because I don't have 'where' for my first table in the sql statement. I can't figure out how to implement the 'where' for each table with different 'foreach' loops. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UNION` will join the results of two different queries. The union is applied after each query has finished executing, so you need two `WHERE` clauses:

```
select [aName],[aDesc] from [Table1]
where ([aName] like '%{0}%' or [aDesc] like '%{0}%')

union

select [bName],[bDesc] from [Table2]
where ([bName] like '%{0}%' or [bDesc] like '%{0}%')
```

The easiest implementation in your code would involve building both queries separately and then joining them together:

```
StringBuilder sqlBuilder = new StringBuilder();
sqlBuilder.Append("select [aName],[aDesc] from [Table1] where ");
foreach (string item in keywords)
{
    sqlBuilder.AppendFormat(
        "([aName] like '%{0}%' or [aDesc] like '%{0}%') and ", item);
}

// That last "AND" requires a boolean statement to follow
// 1=1 will always return true and thus will not affect
// the result of your WHERE clause.
sqlBuilder.Append("1 = 1 ");

sqlBuilder.Append("UNION select [bName],[bDesc] from [Table2] where ");
foreach (string item in keywords)
{
    sqlBuilder.AppendFormat(
        "([bName] like '%{0}%' or [bDesc] like '%{0}%') and ", item);
}
```

An alternative to the `foreach` loops:

```
sqlBuilder.Append("select [aName],[aDesc] from [Table1] where ");
sqlBuilder.Append(
    string.Join(
        " and ",
        keywords.Select( k => string.Format( 
            "([aName] like '%{0}%' or [aDesc] like '%{0}%')", k )
        .ToArray()
    )
)

sqlBuilder.Append("UNION select [bName],[bDesc] from [Table2] where ");
sqlBuilder.Append(
    string.Join(
        " and ",
        keywords.Select( k => string.Format( 
            "([bName] like '%{0}%' or [bDesc] like '%{0}%')", k )
        .ToArray()
    )
)
```

Please note, though, that is going to be an ***extremely*** inefficient query. If you have more than a few hundred rows to search, I ***highly*** recommend you consider alternative approaches.

In addition, your appear to be vulnerable to [SQL Injection attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Unless you are already scrubbing your inputs manually beforehand, you should consider [protecting yourself](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648339.aspx).

[image: [[A woman is talking on the phone, holding a cup]] Phone: Hi, this is your son's school. We're having some computer trouble. Mom: Oh dear—did he break something? Phone: In a way— Phone: Did you really name your son "Robert'); DROP TABLE Students;--" ? Mom: Oh, yes. Little Bobby Tables, we call him. Phone: Well, we've lost this year's student records. I hope you're happy. Mom: And I hope you've learned to sanitize your database inputs. {{title-text: Her daughter is named Help I'm trapped in a driver's license factory.}}]

Comment: @BrianBrian - because of your "uncapped" `AND`, perhaps?

Comment: How do you cap it with 1=1?

Comment: @BrianBrian - updated with a LINQ alternative, in case you don't like `1 = 1` in your query

Comment: I had to switch around the order of the tables, but it works! Thank you very much for your help. I have looked into using Lucene.Net, but will need to do a little more research before I move forward :)